# What's the meaning of this exception for Neo4jImport tool?

Tags: neo4j

I tried to import 372M Nodes, it gave me below exception. After the exception raised, the program could not stop and went on normally. But it may run several hours without any changes for disk usage, cpu and memory. It seems like to be frozen, with just "sort" stuff.   I have replace some special characters. How to solve it ?

Below is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /cygdrive/d/neo4j-enterprise-2.2.0/bin
users="d:\\RiskNetwork\\nodes_header.txt"
for i in /cygdrive/d/RiskNetwork/Nodes/*
do
    users=$users,$(cygpath -w "$i")
done
./Neo4jImport.bat --stacktrace --into ../data/weibo.db --nodes:User $users --delimiter ^A --array-delimiter ^B --quote ^C --id-type STRING
```

Thes are output and exceptions:

```
......
......
[*>:18.42 MB/s-----------------|PROPERTIES(2)==========|NODE:2.72 GB------------  
[*>:18.42 MB/s-----------------|PROPERTIES(2)==========|NODE:2.73 GB------------  
[*>:18.41 MB/s------------------|PROPERTIES(2)========|NODE:2.73 GB-------------  
[*>:18.40 MB/s-----------------|PROPERTIES(2)=========|NODE:2.74 GB-------------  
[*>:18.40 MB/s----------------|PROPERTIES(2)==========|NODE:2.75 GB-------------  
[*>:18.38 MB/s-----------------|PROPERTIES(2)==========|NODE:2.76 GB-----------|  
[*>:18.37 MB/s-------------------|PROPERTIES(2)=========|NODE:2.76 GB-----------  
[*>:18.36 MB/s---------------|PROPERTIES(2)===========|NODE:2.77 GB-------------  
[*>:18.36 MB/s------------------|PROPERTIES(2)==========|NODE:2.78 GB------------|v:57.94 MB/s(]372M
Done in 17m 14s 300ms
Prepare node index
[*SPLIT:2.85 GB-----------------------------------------------------------------  
[*SPLIT:4.11 GB-----------------------------------------------------------------  
[*SPLIT:4.11 GB-----------------------------------------------------------------  
[*SPLIT:4.11 GB-----------------------------------------------------------------  
[*SPLIT:4.11 GB-----------------------------------------------------------------  
[*SPLIT:4.11 GB-----------------------------------------------------------------  
[*SPLIT:4.11 GB-----------------------------------------------------------------  
[*SPLIT:4.11 GB-----------------------------------------------------------------  
[*SPLIT:4.11 GB-----------------------------------------------------------------  
[*SPLIT:4.11 GB-----------------------------------------------------------------  
[*SPLIT:4.11 GB-----------------------------------------------------------------  
[*SPLIT:4.11 GB-----------------------------------------------------------------  
[*SPLIT:4.11 GB-----------------------------------------------------------------  
[*SPLIT:4.11 GB-----------------------------------------------------------------  
[*SPLIT:4.11 GB-----------------------------------------------------------------
[*SPLIT:4.11 GB-----------------------------------------------------------------
[*SPLIT:4.11 GB-----------------------------------------------------------------
......
......
[*SPLIT:4.16 GB-------------------------------------------------------------------
[*SPLIT:4.16 GB-------------------------------------------------------------------
[*SPLIT:4.16 GB-------------------------------------------------------------------
[*SPLIT:4.16 GB-------------------------------------------------------------------
[*SPLIT:4.16 GB-------------------------------------------------------------------
[*SPLIT:4.16 GB-------------------------------------------------------------------
[*SPLIT:4.16 GB-------------------------------------------------------------------
[*SPLIT:4.17 GB-------------------------------------------------------------------
[*SPLIT:4.17 GB-------------------------------------------------------------------
[*SPLIT:4.17 GB-------------------------------------------------------------------
[*SORT:4.17 GB--------------------------------------------------------------------
[*SORT:4.17 GB---------------------------------------------------------------------------------] 
0Exception in thread "SortWorker-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Requested index -1, but length is 1000000
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.OffHeapNumberArray.addressOf(OffHeapNumberArray.java:55)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.OffHeapLongArray.get(OffHeapLongArray.java:42)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.DynamicLongArray.get(DynamicLongArray.java:42)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.ParallelSort.partition(ParallelSort.java:204)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.ParallelSort.recursiveQsort(ParallelSort.java:246)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.ParallelSort.access$100(ParallelSort.java:39)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.ParallelSort$SortWorker.run(ParallelSort.java:296)
[*SORT:4.17 GB--------------------------------------------------------------------
[*SORT:4.17 GB--------------------------------------------------------------------
[*SORT:4.17 GB--------------------------------------------------------------------
[*SORT:4.17 GB--------------------------------------------------------------------
[*SORT:4.17 GB--------------------------------------------------------------------
[*SORT:4.17 GB--------------------------------------------------------------------
[*SORT:4.17 GB--------------------------------------------------------------------
[*SORT:4.17 GB--------------------------------------------------------------------
[*SORT:4.17 GB--------------------------------------------------------------------
[*SORT:4.17 GB--------------------------------------------------------------------
[*SORT:4.17 GB--------------------------------------------------------------------
[*SORT:4.17 GB--------------------------------------------------------------------
[*SORT:4.17 GB--------------------------------------------------------------------
[*SORT:4.17 GB--------------------------------------------------------------------
[*SORT:4.17 GB--------------------------------------------------------------------
[*SORT:4.17 GB--------------------------------------------------------------------
[*SORT:4.17 GB--------------------------------------------------------------------
[*SORT:4.17 GB--------------------------------------------------------------------
[*SORT:4.17 GB--------------------------------------------------------------------
[*SORT:4.17 GB--------------------------------------------------------------------
......

......
```

What's meaning of these Exception? What I can sure is the delimiter, array-delimiter and quote do not appear in the data column context of input files.

Comment: That looks like a bug in the node id index code of the import tool, although I haven't seen it before. I'm the main author of this code and would love to try and reproduce this locally and for that I'd need your csv files, for the single purpose of running the import tool on them and debug what's causing this error. Would that be at all possible?

Comment: @MattiasPersson For the sake of confidential, I cannt not share with you. But I probably found the casuse. Im not sure. I think it may caused by row with "Empty" content in ID Field. I can successfully import these type of row into database. It's wierd. After I deleted this row, the exception above went away.

Comment: OK, thanks. The importer should probably be changed to fail earlier in this case.

Comment: @MattiasPersson Yes. And I may hope you could make the exception message more user friendly to debug especially we are processing files whose size are larger than 500GB+.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/pull/4427 will fix this issue, so hopefully Neo4j version 2.2.1 will contain this fix.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error (but with SortWorker-1 instead of 0) and removing "blank" fields solved it, as suggested by luck in the comments.

By "blank fields", I mean space(s)/tab(s)/... & combination of them.

Comment: Which version were you using? I think they have fixed this bug.

Comment: I'm using Neo4j-entreprise 2.2.1